# Show specific items from database to listview

Tags: android, database, listview

i want to show listview with specific items  , 
i have 2 table :

**table1 :**

```
   +------------+----------+
   | id_table1  |  Item    | 
   +------------+----------+
   | 1          | Item1    |
   | 2          | Item2    |
   | 3          | Item3    |
   | 4          | Item2.1  |
   | 5          | Item2.2  |
   | 6          | Item3.1  |
   | 7          | Item3.2  |
   +------------+----------+
```

**table 2 :** id_table2.table2 = id_table1.table1 and table2.id_table = id_table1.table1

```
   +------------+----------+
   | id_table2  | id_table | 
   +------------+----------+
   | 2          | 4        |
   | 2          | 5        |
   | 3          | 6        |
   | 3          | 7        |
   +------------+----------+
```

and i want to show it on listview android , that will be look like this :
[image]

Comment: Awesome! What have you tried?

Comment: i try merge adapter library, so `item2.1`, `item2.2` is under listview `item1`,`item2``item3` with header `item2`, but i have another problem to show a header for `item3`that have a `item3.1`,`item3.2` , i haven't found a proper example yet, so i'm a very hard confused about how to make it works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want an Expandable List View here is a good tutorial that helped me:
[Expandable List View](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)